# How to check if an external window was launched or restored (inactive) when an web page has been rendered?

Tags: javascript, browser, overlay, autohotkey

Is there any way we can ensure that there is absolutely no overlay (inactive window) over an webpage being rendered on a browser?

focus, blur and visibility listener logic does the work for an active window.

But what about an inactive window that is using something like AlwaysOnTop with the help of AHK?

Is there any way in JS to detect that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening for the [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) event?